# How can I preventing sparks from a plasma tube arcing onto electromagnet

Tags: voltage, audio, electromagnetism, physics, tesla-coil

I'm building a very small version of this it's a Plasma tube with an electromagnet (the two red coils) wrapped around the tube [see link](http://scied-web.pppl.gov/RGDX/) or image below. [image: Plasma tube]

I want to send **AC and DC Signals** into the electromagnetic coil wrapped around the plasma tube using an audio receiver, DC power supply, and an amp (I want to see how different signals effect the plasma).  The problem I have is arcing, how can I prevent the arcs created by the plasma tube from interacting with my electromagnetic coils wrapped around the tube?  (I don't want the arc travelling down and frying my receiver which is powering the electromagnet).

What I'm using is a Tesla Violet ray wand (see image below) also here's [link to a video of one being taken apart](https://youtu.be/5fuTnh6ofjY?t=9m) along with a circuit explained.  I'm using this as the plasma tube and high voltage source and wrapping wire around the little plasma tube and sending the ac/dc signal into the coil. How can I prevent the arcs created by the plasma tube from interacting with my electromagnetic coils around the tube?  (I don't want the arc travelling down and frying my receiver).
[image: Tesla wand]

The kit looks something like this [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001VII87W).
Video of it being taken apart [Link](https://youtu.be/5fuTnh6ofjY?t=9m).

Comment: If it arcs, then you are overdriving the coil feed. It should be <1 mA of current thru the coil , not hundreds of mA.  You can modulate the plasma current by conduction current or induction coil and use a 21MHz carrier and modulate with audio frequencies if you like.

Comment: What audio amplifier are you using that includes DC? Most have a high pass filter to prevent DC from getting to (and damaging) the speakers.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I've included a video link to one being taken apart with the circuit https://youtu.be/5fuTnh6ofjY?t=9m

Comment: @JRE Sorry about that I should have added that I was also going to use a DC power supply.  I've added that to the question along 
with the Darsonval style modern Violet Wand Ray unit taken apart.
https://youtu.be/5fuTnh6ofjY?t=9m

Comment: One can modulate the rep rate with external energy or use the pot. But you cannot modulate the rise time with this, as this is   dependent on target dielectric and air gap.   Much more explanation is needed to model the complex non-linear equivalent circuit.  Consider measuring the spectrum with an SA or use a Falstad's Fourier generator to understand what harmonics to expect.  A thorough understanding or Microwave theory is needed as well as plasma impedance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAUAPE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the epoxy insulated autotransformer is rated about 10kV/mm and is ~10mm thick thus perhaps running around 50kV but current limited by impedance of secondary and tube.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGXonD.png)</sup>

understand that the impedances of each gas element are dynamic RLC and negative  ΔR when conducting thus impulse currents.  ( somewhat like how an SCR works)

Small arcs may have <1ns rise time due to speed of light over gap which can be reduced to <<1mm giving rise to low energy microwave and then Infrared and then X-Rays as current exceeds a modified design with absorption into skin.

Current is limited by all series elements and arcs occur in the smallest gap in air using ~ 1~3kV/mm rule of thumb.

The best way to protect it is like with ESD.  10K series R and 2 stage Schottky diodes to both rails just like in CMOS.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Alhi.png)</sup>

Here is an example of a 1mm gap of a discharge arc current limited  but duty cycle from low rep rate about 10ns every 16ms thus only 0.2uJ energy. If rep rate was 20kHz, the energy would rise from 60Hz to 67uJ.

The rise time was in fact limited by the 300MHz BW of the Le Croy scope but you could hear it on SW and UHF radio. Here I used a short loop wire around the ground current to 50 Ohm load . The delayed pulse was thru a longer coax using a 10:1 probe shorted to gnd around feed wire. Loop Orientation was reversed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for makes no sense.

If you get any arcing outside the plasma tube, fix that first.

If this "arc" you talk about is the one existing in the plasma in the tube, then it's not clear what problem you are trying to address.  The arc is on the other side of some glass.  I don't see how you expect this to hurt what is connected to the coils, since the arc is not connected to the coils.

Since the plasma inside the tube becomes a conductor, it will have a magnetic field around it circularly.  Your coils are aligned such that they will pick up or cause magnetic fields parallel to the current in the plasma.  It's not clear what you think the purpose of this is.

If you want the coils to interact with the current in the plasma, then the *magnetic* field needs to loop around the plasma tube.  That means the electric current needs to loop around that.  In other words, you need to wrap the wire around a toroidal core, then have the plasma tube go thru the center of the toroid.